# Cascading Drop Down Page Refresh

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

I have been trying everything I can to get this script to work and I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm very new to PHP and Javascript and I am trying to modify a script I found on the internet to get cascading drop downs on my site. This is a fairly simple script that unfortunately doesn't use AJAX so it requires a page refresh but if Im having a hard time with this I don't think I should move on to AJAX quite yet. The problem I'm having is the script is supposed to make my selection from menu one stick when the page refreshes but it always resets back to SELECT ONE, the default. It works in the original script but Ive made quite a few modifications so I can't figure out why mine is not sticking. The original script is:

```
<?php
//***************************************
// This is downloaded from www.plus2net.com //
/// You can distribute this code with the link to www.plus2net.com ///
//  Please don't  remove the link to www.plus2net.com ///
// This is for your learning only not for commercial use. ///////
//The author is not responsible for any type of loss or problem or damage on using this script.//
/// You can use it at your own risk. /////
//*****************************************

$dbservertype='mysql';
$servername='localhost';
// username and password to log onto db server
$dbusername='';
$dbpassword='';
// name of database
$dbname='dd';

////////////////////////////////////////
////// DONOT EDIT BELOW  /////////
///////////////////////////////////////
connecttodb($servername,$dbname,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
function connecttodb($servername,$dbname,$dbuser,$dbpassword)
{
global $link;
$link=mysql_connect ("$servername","$dbuser","$dbpassword");
if(!$link){die("Could not connect to MySQL");}
mysql_select_db("$dbname",$link) or die ("could not open db".mysql_error());
}
//////// End of connecting to database ////////
?>

<!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 3.2//en">

<html>

<head>
<title>Multiple drop down list box from plus2net</title>
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript>
function reload(form)
{
var val=form.cat.options[form.cat.options.selectedIndex].value;
self.location='dd.php?cat=' + val ;
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<?

/*
If register_global is off in your server then after reloading of the page to get the value of cat from query string we have to take special care.
To read more on register_global visit.
  http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/register-globals.php
*/
@$cat=$_GET['cat']; // Use this line or below line if register_global is off
if(strlen($cat) > 0 and !is_numeric($cat)){ // to check if $cat is numeric data or not. 
echo "Data Error";
exit;
}


//@$cat=$HTTP_GET_VARS['cat']; // Use this line or above line if register_global is off

///////// Getting the data from Mysql table for first list box//////////
$quer2=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT category,cat_id FROM category order by category"); 
///////////// End of query for first list box////////////

/////// for second drop down list we will check if category is selected else we will display all the subcategory///// 
if(isset($cat) and strlen($cat) > 0){
$quer=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT subcategory FROM subcategory where cat_id=$cat order by subcategory"); 
}else{$quer=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT subcategory FROM subcategory order by subcategory"); } 
////////// end of query for second subcategory drop down list box ///////////////////////////

echo "<form method=post name=f1 action='dd-check.php'>";
/// Add your form processing page address to action in above line. Example  action=dd-check.php////
//////////        Starting of first drop downlist /////////
echo "<select name='cat' onchange=\"reload(this.form)\"><option value=''>Select one</option>";
while($noticia2 = mysql_fetch_array($quer2)) { 
if($noticia2['cat_id']==@$cat)
{echo "<option selected value='$noticia2[cat_id]'>$noticia2[category]</option>"."<BR>";}
else{echo  "<option value='$noticia2[cat_id]'>$noticia2[category]</option>";}
}
echo "</select>";
//////////////////  This will end the first drop down list ///////////

//////////        Starting of second drop downlist /////////
echo "<select name='subcat'><option value=''>Select one</option>";
while($noticia = mysql_fetch_array($quer)) { 
echo  "<option value='$noticia[subcategory]'>$noticia[subcategory]</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
//////////////////  This will end the second drop down list ///////////
//// Add your other form fields as needed here/////
echo "<input type=submit value=Submit>";
echo "</form>";
?>
<center><a href='http://www.plus2net.com'>PHP SQL HTML free tutorials and scripts</a></center> 
</body>

</html>
```

And my script is:

```
<?php
$dbservertype='mysql';
$servername='localhost';
$dbusername='newuser';
$dbpassword='';
$dbname='supplydb';
connecttodb($servername,$dbname,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
function connecttodb($servername,$dbname,$dbuser,$dbpassword){
global $link;
$link=mysql_connect ("$servername","$dbuser","$dbpassword");
if(!$link){die("Could not connect to MySQL");}
mysql_select_db("$dbname",$link) or die ("could not open db".mysql_error());}
?>
<!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 3.2//en">
<html>
<head>
<title>Multiple drop down list box from plus2net</title>
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript>
function reload(form){
var val=form.category.options[form.category.options.selectedIndex].text;
self.location='dd.php?cat=' + val ;
}
function reload2(form)
{
var val=form.cat.options[form.cat.options.selectedIndex].text; 
var val2=form.subcat.options[form.subcat.options.selectedIndex].text; 
self.location='dd.php?cat=' + val + '&cat2=' + val2 ;
console.log(val2);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?

//////  Grab Get after page refresh
$cat=$_GET['cat'];
$command="SELECT * FROM product_group WHERE type = 1";
$quer2 = mysql_query($command);
    if(isset($cat) and strlen($cat) > 1){
        $num = explode(' ',$cat);
        $number = $num[0];      
        $strLen = strlen( $number );
            for ( $i = 0; $i < $strLen; $i++ )
                {$arr[] = $number{$i};}
                $arr1 = $arr [0];
                $arr2 = $arr [1];
                $arr3 = $arr1.$arr2;                
$command1="SELECT * FROM `product_group` WHERE `group` LIKE '".$arr3."%' AND type = '2'";
$quer = mysql_query($command1);
        }       
echo "<form method=post name=category action='dd-check.php'>";

    /////////////   Create First Drop Down Box
    echo "<select name='category' onchange=\"reload(this.form)\"><option value=''>Select one</option>";
        while($query = mysql_fetch_assoc($quer2)){
            if($query['group']==$cat){
                echo "<option selected value='$query[group]'>$query[group]</option>"."<BR>";}
                else {echo "<option value='$query[group]'>$query[group]</option>";}
                }
    echo "</select>";
    //////////////  Create Second Drop Down Box 
    echo "<select name='subcat' onchange=\"reload2(this.form)\"><option value=''>Select one</option>";
        while($query2 = mysql_fetch_array($quer)){      
        if($query2['group']==$cat2)
            {echo "<option selected value='$query2[group]'>$query2[group]</option>"."<BR>";}
        else {echo  "<option value='$query2[group]'>$query2[group]</option>";}
        }





    echo "</select>";

echo "</form>";
print_r ($cat);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help in pointing out where my bonehead mistake is will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Formatting your code properly would really help. There's your first mistake.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to fix this right now...

Comment: Use spaces instead of tabs, and ensure that you prefix every line with at least four spaces. BTW, don't you think HTML3.2 is a bit old?

Comment: Please note that in the original script, the name of the select element is 'cat' and the its value is retrieved using $_GET['cat'] while in your script you have changed the name of the select to 'category' while still trying to get the value using $_GET['cat'].

Comment: Thanks Yaniro. That was one problem and the other is in my answer. In my selects I was querying group both for the value and what was showing. I needed an id field for the value. Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Sorry for the formatting problems. I'll run all code through a formatter from now on. In the original code they are calling for an ID field that I didn't even have setup in my database. Once I setup the field and corrected the code it worked perfectly.